# Unable to move character to right position using SDL?

Tags: c++, sdl, sdl2

I am currently having problem moving a character right and showing him like he's running but after i press right key it moves right for one time and then when i enter left it goes left again but pressing right again doesn't make it go to right again. Here is my code that i am using :

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

#include "game.h"
#include "graphics.h"
#include "input.h"

/* Game class
*  This class holds all information for our game loop
*/

namespace {
    const int FPS = 50;
    const int MAX_FRAME_TIME = 5 * 1000/ FPS;
}
Game::Game() {
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
    this->gameLoop();
}
Game::~Game() {

}
void Game::gameLoop() {
    Graphics graphics;
    Input input;
    SDL_Event event;

    this->_player = Player(graphics, 100, 100);

    int LAST_UPDATE_TIME = SDL_GetTicks();
    //Start the game loop
    while(true){
        input.beginNewFrame();

        if(SDL_PollEvent(&event)){
            if(event.type == SDL_KEYDOWN){
                if(event.key.repeat == 0){
                    input.keyDownEvent(event);
                }
            }
            else if(event.type == SDL_KEYUP){
                input.keyUpEvent(event);
            }
            else if(event.type == SDL_QUIT){
                return;
            }
        }
        if(input.wasKeyPressed(SDL_SCANCODE_ESCAPE) == true){
            return;
        }
        else if(input.isKeyHeld(SDL_SCANCODE_LEFT) == true) {
            this->_player.moveLeft();
        }
        else if(input.isKeyHeld(SDL_SCANCODE_RIGHT) == true) {
            this->_player.moveRight();
        }

        if(!input.isKeyHeld(SDL_SCANCODE_LEFT) && !input.isKeyHeld(SDL_SCANCODE_RIGHT)){
            this->_player.stopMoving();
        }

    const int CURRENT_TIME_MS = SDL_GetTicks();
    int ELAPSED_TIME_MS = CURRENT_TIME_MS - LAST_UPDATE_TIME;
    this->update(std::min(ELAPSED_TIME_MS, MAX_FRAME_TIME));
    LAST_UPDATE_TIME = CURRENT_TIME_MS;

    this->draw(graphics);
}

}
void Game::draw(Graphics &graphics){
    graphics.clear();

    this->_player.draw(graphics);

    graphics.flip();

}
void Game::update(float elapsedTime){
    this->_player.update(elapsedTime);
}
```

and for player.cpp

```
#include "player.h"
#include "graphics.h"

namespace player_constants {
    const float WALK_SPEED = 0.2f;
}

Player::Player() {}

Player::Player(Graphics &graphics, float x, float y) :
    AnimatedSprite(graphics, "MyChar.png", 0, 0, 16, 16, x, y, 100)
    {
        graphics.loadImage("MyChar.png");

        this->setupAnimations();
        this->playAnimation("RunRight");
    }
void Player::setupAnimations() {
    this->addAnimation(1, 0, 0, "IdleLeft", 16, 16, Vector2(0,0));
    this->addAnimation(1, 0, 16, "IdleRight", 16, 16, Vector2(0,0));
    this->addAnimation(3, 0, 0, "RunLeft", 16, 16, Vector2(0,0));
    this->addAnimation(3, 0, 16, "RunRight", 16, 16, Vector2(0,0));
}

void Player::animationDone(std::string currentAnimation) {}

void Player::moveLeft(){
    this->_dx = -player_constants::WALK_SPEED;
    this->playAnimation("RunLeft");
    this->_facing = LEFT;

}
void Player::moveRight(){
    this->_dx = player_constants::WALK_SPEED;
    this->playAnimation("RunRight");
    this->_facing = RIGHT;

}

void Player::stopMoving() {
    this->_dx = 0.0f;
    this->playAnimation(this->_facing == RIGHT ? "IdleRight" : "IdleLeft");
}
void Player::update(float elapsedTime) {
    //Move by dx
    this->_x += this->_dx * elapsedTime;

    AnimatedSprite::update(elapsedTime);
}

void Player::draw(Graphics &graphics) {
    AnimatedSprite::draw(graphics, this->_x, this->_y);
}
```

EDIT:

Input.cpp file

```
#include "input.h"

/* Input class
* Keeps track of keyboard state
*/
//This function gets called at the beginning of each new frame
//to reset the keys that are no longer relevant
void Input::beginNewFrame(){
    this->_pressedKeys.clear();
    this->_releasedKeys.clear();
}

void Input::keyDownEvent(const SDL_Event& event){
    this->_pressedKeys[event.key.keysym.scancode] = true;
    this->_heldKeys[event.key.keysym.scancode] = true;
}
//this gets called when a key is released
void Input::keyUpEvent(const SDL_Event& event){
    this->_releasedKeys[event.key.keysym.scancode] = true;
    this->_heldKeys[event.key.keysym.scancode] = true;
}
//check if a certain key was pressed during the current frame
bool Input::wasKeyPressed(SDL_Scancode key){
    return this->_pressedKeys[key];
}
//check if a certain key was released during the current frame
bool Input::wasKeyReleased(SDL_Scancode key){
    return this->_releasedKeys[key];
}
//check if a certain key is currently being held
bool Input::isKeyHeld(SDL_Scancode key){
    return this->_heldKeys[key];
}
```

The main functions are 'moveLeft()', 'moveRight()' and 'stopMoving()' in player.cpp file above.

I think there's some problem in player.cpp file, can anyone help me with this as i have been trying to fix the problem for more than 3 hours. Thank you.

Comment: It sounds like you need to narrow down the problem. Could you post a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, after spending more than 2 days on this problem, i found the bug as you can see above in Input.cpp in the following line:

```
void Input::keyUpEvent(const SDL_Event& event){
    this->_releasedKeys[event.key.keysym.scancode] = true;
    this->_heldKeys[event.key.keysym.scancode] = true;
}
```

`_heldKeys` should be made `false` for it to work properly.

Answer (score 1):

One obvious issue I see in your code is in the event loop of your `Game::gameLoop` method. You're using `if(SDL_PollEvent(&event))` where the common pattern for event **looping** in SDL is `while(SDL_PollEvent(&event))`. Without more code it's hard to say if something else might cause the problem, but that one line might just be your problem. Even if it isn't it's better to process more than one event per frame, otherwise the user might experience annoying input lag.

Just making a wild guess here, but I guess it also might be a problem with your `Input` class, perhaps not reseting some variables.